flutter_map_marker_cluster opening of the cluster
While using flutter_map_marker_cluster is it possible to give padding to the markers that open when a cluster is clicked?
Since there is an appbar on top of the application screen and a bottom navigation bar below it, some opened markers can remain behind them.
